# Why do I have the following error (MassTransit)

Tags: masstransit

The error is -
ConfigurationException: A receive endpoint with the same key was already added: Events

I have appsettings.Development.json with

```
"EventsBusOptions": {
    "HostUri": "rabbitmq://rabbitmq.test.com/gate",
    "UserName": "xxx",
    "Password": "xxxxxx",
    "QueueName": "events", //<<< if is change queue name some different string e.g. "events1" - NO error
    "PrefetchCount": 16,
    "UseConcurrencyLimit": 15
  }
```

and Startup.cs (with MultiBus Configuration)

```
    services.AddMassTransit<IEventsBus>(x =>
    {
        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            var _options = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EventsBusOptions>>().Value;

            cfg.Host(new Uri(_options.HostUri), h =>
            {
                h.Username(_options.UserName);
                h.Password(_options.Password);
            });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(_options.QueueName, ep =>
            {
                ep.Consumer<EventsConsumer>(context);
                ep.PrefetchCount = _options.PrefetchCount ?? 15;
                ep.UseConcurrencyLimit(_options.UseConcurrencyLimit ?? 16);
            });

            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });

        x.AddConsumer<EventsConsumer>();

    });
```

Why I have got the error when I use  "QueueName": "events"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using the *wrong* method to configure the consumer. `ConfigureConsumer` should be used instead of just `Consumer`, as shown in the updated configuration below.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit<IEventsBus>(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<EventsConsumer>();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        var _options = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EventsBusOptions>>().Value;

        cfg.Host(new Uri(_options.HostUri), h =>
        {
            h.Username(_options.UserName);
            h.Password(_options.Password);
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(_options.QueueName, ep =>
        {
            ep.PrefetchCount = _options.PrefetchCount ?? 16;
            ep.ConcurrentMessageLimit = _options.ConcurrentMessageLimit ?? 16;

            ep.ConfigureConsumer<EventsConsumer>(context);
        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

**NOTE** I also fixed your concurrent message limit configuration to use the built-in limiter, instead of adding a filter.

**ALSO** you could leave off `ConfigureEndpoints` since you're manually configuring the receive endpoint for the consumer.